# Escape special characters

Tags: .net, html, .net-2.0, c#-2.0, special-characters

My code below seems to be encoding special charcters how do I get it to escape these?

```
 str1 += myGridView.Rows[idx].Cells[2].Text + ";";
```

When i check the grid view html source the table cell text is = '`http://news.google.co.uk/nwshp?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tab=wn&q=Clifford+Chance&output=rss`'

But the value for str1 is '`http://news.google.co.uk/nwshp?ie=UTF-8&amp;hl=en&amp;tab=wn&amp;q=Clifford+Chance&amp;output=rss;`'

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing here is the HTML control encoding your text to HTML so it appears in the client's browser as it does in your string.

You can use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to decode an encoded string of HTML.